# How to send a string in to the address bar onLoad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, ip-address

I dont know even if this is possible. I first saw this on google. If you notice when you type a query and you press enter the result appear and only after this the link in the address bar changes. I believe they use this in case someone refreshes the page the results will be the same. How is this possible? whit javascript? jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location#Properties) in JavaScript code. For a nicer interface, use a jQuery [history plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347168/jquery-history-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the new HTML5 history.pushState() - then you can replace much more than just the part after the hash.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history