# Update browser's URL without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, browser-history, pushstate

Is it possible to change the URL shown in the browser's address bar without having the browser go to that page? Such as, for example, after updating a page's content via an AJAX call?

My understanding is that this is not possible, which is why sites such as twitter and facebook update the hash-tag on ajax calls.

That is until today, when I went on http://8tracks.com/ and started to play with the filter on the right hand side... turning different genres on and off, I noticed that even though it was doing ajax calls to refresh the content on the page, the URL was also being dynamically updated.

Does anyone know how they do this?

(aside, I'm currently using Chrome, but when I went back and looked again with IE9, I noticed that the URL was not being updated.. is this maybe a Chrome only thing?)

Answer (score 21):

This is possible in modern browsers by using the HTML5 History API:

```
history.pushState(null, null, '/some-path')
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method

This works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari (not IE).

Comment: +1 for this answer. HTML5 History API is the correct/only way to do this. For a background article you can check out https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling which explains the evolution of hashes to hashbangs to the HTML5 History API.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use Jquery history plugin.  This will give support to html4 browsers as well.

Here is an article talking about it: http://veerasundaravel.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/change-browser-url-with-reloading-the-page-jquery-html5/

here is another question that gives more options: [jQuery History Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347168/jquery-history-plugin)