# ASP MVC3 Ajax razor view, How to enable browser history?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, browser-history

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 3  application, I am using razor view. I have a main page which has 4 links. These links are used to render partial views into the main page. currently I am using @ajax.ActionLink() method to render views. As it asynchronously works I am not able to use browser navigation buttons to navigate through these different pages.

How to make back button to work with ajax? please help me

Comment: You could use a jquery history plugin : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347168/jquery-history-plugin

Comment: can any body provide me simple sample which is using BBQ jquery plugin in MVC3 asp.net Ajax?

Comment: Googling it, this is the first link : http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Comment: M not able to use this plugin inmy application, anyway thanks.. I have to study these examples little more

Comment: Hi Suma, check this [http://ajaxhistory.com/example](http://ajaxhistory.com/example/)

Comment: I found something useful, check this [http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/contact-manager/iteration-7-add-ajax-functionality-cs] (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/contact-manager/iteration-7-add-ajax-functionality-cs) section : **Adding Browser History Support**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/enabling-the-back-button/

Comment: the link is broken (502)

Comment: the link seems ok for me!

Comment: indeed , it now works for me too, must have been a transient issue