# How to prevent Browser Default Behaviour on pressing Cntl(Command)+sideArrow In Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to prevent default browser behaviour of hitting Cntl+sideArrow in firefox which navigates to previous and next pages.Is there any way to disable that and enable again using any front end technologies like jquery,javascript ?

Comment: Different platforms use different key combinations and gestures for navigation, and most have more than one of each for the same navigation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change that. This behavior is baked into the browser and while add-ons can change it, client-side script cannot.

Answer (score 0):

in terms of user experience and best practice in web design user should always be able to use browser's Back and Forward button.

### To handle standard HTML form post:

after submitted redirect request to display result page.

### To handle ajax post history

see: [jQuery History Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347168/jquery-history-plugin)

### If You really need it

You can't prevent browser navigate 'Back' and 'Forward' command but You could access to

`window.history` object which contains URLs to navigate back.